# Randomly generated Firebase child key in document path SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I've had a look around and although there is some answers which are similar I can't find what I'm specifically looking for.

My data is stored in Firebase (Cloud Firestore) and I need to read that data back which is fine and working. My issue is I have changed the setup of the document file path to further increase security by adding a randomly generated id in the file path.

Firstly, is this possible to add the wildcard into a document path within Xcode? Secondly, could this be perhaps done as a string?

I have added the code below including file path.

Thanks in advance.

```
class getContactData : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var datas = [contactDataType]()
    @AppStorage("selectedSchool") var selectedSchool: String = "selectedSchool"
    
    init() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("/School Name/\(selectedSchool)/School Assets/**randomPath**/Contact Details").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
            
            if err != nil{
                
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            for i in snap!.documents{
                
                let id = i.documentID
                let adno = i.get("ID") as! String
                let fullname = i.get("Full Name") as! String
                let firstname = i.get("First Name") as! String
                let lastname = i.get("Last Name") as! String
                let registrationgroup = i.get("Registration Group") as! String
                let priority1relation = i.get("Priority 1 Relation") as! String
                let priority1fullname = i.get("Priority 1 Full Name") as! String
                let priority1maintelephone = i.get("Priority 1 Main Telephone") as! String
                let priority1mobile = i.get("Priority 1 Mobile") as! String
                let priority2relation = i.get("Priority 2 Relation") as! String
                let priority2fullname = i.get("Priority 2 Full Name") as! String
                let priority2maintelephone = i.get("Priority 2 Main Telephone") as! String
                let priority2mobile = i.get("Priority 2 Mobile") as! String
                let priority3relation = i.get("Priority 3 Relation") as! String
                let priority3fullname = i.get("Priority 3 Full Name") as! String
                let priority3maintelephone = i.get("Priority 3 Main Telephone") as! String
                let priority3mobile = i.get("Priority 3 Mobile") as! String
                let priority4relation = i.get("Priority 4 Relation") as! String
                let priority4fullname = i.get("Priority 4 Full Name") as! String
                let priority4maintelephone = i.get("Priority 4 Main Telephone") as! String
                let priority4mobile = i.get("Priority 4 Mobile") as! String
                
                
                self.datas.append(contactDataType(id: id, adno: adno, fullname: fullname, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, registrationgroup: registrationgroup, priority1relation: priority1relation, priority1fullname: priority1fullname, priority1maintelephone: priority1maintelephone, priority1mobile: priority1mobile, priority2relation: priority2relation, priority2fullname: priority2fullname, priority2maintelephone: priority2maintelephone, priority2mobile: priority2mobile, priority3relation: priority3relation, priority3fullname: priority3fullname, priority3maintelephone: priority3maintelephone, priority3mobile: priority3mobile, priority4relation: priority4relation, priority4fullname: priority4fullname, priority4maintelephone: priority4maintelephone, priority4mobile: priority4mobile))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct contactDataType : Identifiable {
    
    var id : String
    var adno : String
    var fullname : String
    var firstname : String
    var lastname : String
    var registrationgroup : String
    var priority1relation : String
    var priority1fullname : String
    var priority1maintelephone : String
    var priority1mobile : String
    var priority2relation : String
    var priority2fullname : String
    var priority2maintelephone : String
    var priority2mobile : String
    var priority3relation : String
    var priority3fullname : String
    var priority3maintelephone : String
    var priority3mobile : String
    var priority4relation : String
    var priority4fullname : String
    var priority4maintelephone : String
    var priority4mobile : String
```

Comment: Just a few comments: check out Firebase's Codable support - this will make mapping documents to your app's data structs a lot easier and less error prone: https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/ . Also, class names should start with an uppercase letter (see https://google.github.io/swift/). I'd also recommend not using verbs in class names. Consider using `ContactsStore` or `ContactsRepository` instead of `getConatctData`. Last, but not least - avoid using Swift's force unwrap operator.

Comment: Regarding your security by obscurity approach: this doesn't make things more secure at all. Instead, you should implement proper Security Rules to keep your data safe: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the info! It's my first application so definitely a huge learning curve. I'll look into codable and I'm already working on the force unwrapping as I know it isn't great after more thorough research. 

I have already implemented security rules and they work well it was from an upload perspective so I could upload from a school and not have the path tampered with to upload to another document if that makes sense.

Comment: Codable is the way forward! Thank you @Peter Friese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does not support wildcards in queries.

If you want to query all documents among all subcollections named "Contact Details" anywhere in the database, then you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#swift_14).

```
db.collectionGroup("Contact Details").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, I’ll give this a go! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Firebase, if you add a new .document() without specifying the name of the document, it will create a document with a random generated ID. This is not a wildcard, but it will be a random path.

```
    let firstCollection = "School Name"
    let selectedSchool = "Selected School"
    let secondCollection = "School Assets"
    let thirdCollection = "Contact Details"
    
    // Adding a document:
    let newDocument = db.collection(firstCollection).document(selectedSchool).collection(secondCollection).document()
    let randomPath = newDocument.documentID // You will need to store this if you need to access it directly later
    let finalPath = newDocument.collection(thirdCollection)
    finalPath.addDocument(data: ["info" : "info"], completion: nil)
```

Side note: it's best practice to keep the names of your collections and documents in the database lowercased and without spaces to avoid typing String errors ("School Name" -> "school_name").

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the reply. Yes, im not adding a document from the client side but literally just reading the ones which are already there. It’s allowing the app to read from a query within the database which contains a random ID